# Proving that if $A$ is diagonalisable then $\chi_A(A) = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This could be a very simple question to answer, but I'm unsure how to prove this.

> If you have a diagonalisable matrix $A$, prove that $\chi_A(A)$ is the zero matrix.

(where $\chi_A(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$).

I can show easily that (assuming $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix) that $\chi_A(A)v = 0$ for each eigenvector $v$. There are $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors, so that means $\chi_A(A)v_i = 0$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$, where each $v_i$ is an eigenvector with a distinct eigenvalue.

I guess I know $\chi_A(A)V = 0$ where $V$ is the matrix with the eigenvectors as columns.

I don't know where to go from here, it's probably staring me in the face.

Comment: You are asked to prove a special case of Cayley-Hamilton's Theorem. Prove it for a two by two diagonal matrix and then see how you can generalize that.

Comment: You should think of matrices as linear maps fron $V$ to itself. What you want to prove is "$\chi _A(A)$ is the zero map". What you have shown so far is "$\chi_A(A)$ sends every vector to zero". But those are just the same thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\chi_A(A)$ is $0$ on each vector of a basis, $\chi_A(A)$ is $0$ on the whole space.

Answer (score 0):

If we write $A=PDP^{-1}$ then it is not hard to show that $q(A)=Pq(D)P^{-1}$ for any polynomial $q$, so the problem reduces to the case where $A$ is itself diagonal. Can you see why the result is true for diagonal matrices?